# Flutter firebase_auth signInWithCredential is not working on android

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Greetings flutter developers am developing an app for iOS and android which uses phone auth to authenticate users everything works fine in iOS but for android when this line is called I get an error :

```
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

the error :

> E/flutter (14190): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
>   E/flutter (14190): PlatformException(error, null reference, null)
>   E/flutter (14190): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:551:7)
>   E/flutter (14190): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:292:18)
>   E/flutter (14190): 
>   E/flutter (14190): #2      FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential (file:///Users/pocketcarage/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.8.0+1/lib/src/firebase_auth.dart:211:54)
>   E/flutter (14190): 
>   E/flutter (14190): #3      _RegisterState.signIn (package:pocketcarage_official/UI/register.dart:92:43)
>   E/flutter (14190): 
>   E/flutter (14190): #4      _RegisterState.smsCodeDialog.. (package:pocketcarage_official/UI/register.dart:77:23)
>   E/flutter (14190): #5      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:507:14)
>   E/flutter (14190): #6      _InkResponseState.build. (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:562:30)
>   E/flutter (14190): #7      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
>   E/flutter (14190): #8      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9)
>   E/flutter (14190): #9      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:175:7)
>   E/flutter (14190): #10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:315:9)
>   E/flutter (14190): #11     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:73:12)
>   E/flutter (14190): #12     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:11)
>   E/flutter (14190): #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:180:19)
>   E/flutter (14190): #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:22)
>   E/flutter (14190): #15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:138:7)
>   E/flutter (14190): #16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
>   E/flutter (14190): #17     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:85:7)
>   E/flutter (14190): #18     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:168:13)
>   E/flutter (14190): #19     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:122:5)

which states PlatformException(error, null reference, null) that there is null reference although it works 100% on iPhone . I searched and I found that there's some problems with flutter plugins and a solution would be migrating to androidx and I tried but I keep getting required compilesdk at least 28 and I already changed it what should I do ?

this is the code that's get called

```
Future<String> signIn(String smsCode) async {

final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
  verificationId: verificationId,
  smsCode: smsCode,
);

final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);


final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
DatabaseReference user_db = pDatabase.reference().child("users");
DatabaseReference phone_id = pDatabase.reference().child("phone_id");

String uid = user.uid;
usersModel new_user = new usersModel();
new_user.phone=_phoneController.text;
new_user.email=_emailController.text;
new_user.name=_nameController.text;
user_db.child(uid).child("name").set(new_user.userName);
user_db.child(uid).child("phone").set(new_user.userPhone);
user_db.child(uid).child("email").set(new_user.userEmail);
phone_id.child(new_user.userPhone).set(uid);
assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
Navigator.pop(context);
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/Home');
return 'signInWithPhoneNumber succeeded: $user';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE: After making the following changes to my project, the login method seems to be working:**

In pubspec.yaml:
  updated the sdk version from ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0" to ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

In android/build.gradle:
  updated the dependency for com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1 to use version 3.2.1
 updated the dependency for com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1 to use version 4.2.0

Also, since there ended up being a gradle issue with multidexing after these changes, I updated the android/app/build.gradle file to have a "multiDexEnabled true" property under defaultConfig and added "implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'" to the buildTypes

---

OP:

Someone else has noticed the same issue, and has filed an Issue on the repository for the firebase_auth Dart package: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28057

Comment: I have done the changes but still, I am getting the error when I enter OTP manually.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. This worked for me.

```
(await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
```

Answer (score 3):

i have same issue,after searching full day i solve problem, problem is in the depandcy please add following depandancy

google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+1
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.1+1

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
      final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verificationId,
        smsCode: smsOTP,
      );
      final FirebaseUser user =
          (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
} catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
    }
```